# In the path loss formula for distance calculation, is the path loss represented by txPower - adjusted RSSI?

Tags: signal-processing, ibeacon-android, altbeacon, beacon

I am assuming that the path loss formula is based on L=10nlog(d) and by flipping it around we get d = 10^(L/(10n)). By looking at the algorithm in the library, the numerator L takes the form of txPower - adjusted RSSI or more specifically L = txPower - m*RSSI+C. So am I right to assume that we calculate path loss as the difference between the reference RSSI and the current RSSI (adjusted)?
I am asking this because most sources I have seen define the path loss (dB) as the ratio of transmit power to received power. Since our values are already in decibels, I deduced that this is why we subtract (since log(a/b) = log(a)-log(b)).

Is my reasoning correct?
I am just trying to make sure, since all my calculations are based on the assumption that L = txPower - adjusted RSSI.

Comment: Good deduction!  Yes, I believe this is correct.

Comment: This is a rf/signal processing theory question, not a programming question. It might be better suited for electronics.stackexchange.com or DSP.stackexchange.com.